# IIS Express or IIS for developing Classic ASP?

Tags: iis, asp-classic

Wondering if I should stick with testing on my local IIS install or just use the Express version. Any reason why or why not?

Comment: Any reason why classic ASP and why not .Net flavors?

Comment: Both support Classic ASP, so it'd boil down to the feature grid of IIS vs. Express, and your requirements.

Comment: Yeah because I have oodles of legacy ASP code and it's not yet practical to convert everything. Didn't know if one was peppier than another. I got used to being able to easily start/stop/move Apache and miss that in IIS.

Answer (score 2):

generally, I would try to have the development / testing environment resemble your live environment as closely as possible.
so if you're using IIS in production, I'd recommend using it in development also.

I cannot tell you how many times I've seen web apps working perfectly on the development machine using IIS6, and crashing completely on IIS7.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest this configuration:

- IIS Express on the developer machine
- same IIS as in production on a staging machine

IIS Express is the best choiche on your local computer because it's easy and fast to install and configure and doesn't require administrative rights to be installed.
It's completely integrated with Visual Studio and it has all the functionality of IIS.
And the configuration is in the source code repository so each developer can checkout the solution and is able to run it with minimal effort.

As sJhonny suggests is recommended to have an environment closer as possible to the production environment.
The best way is to have a staging server with the same software configuration of the production server, in your case with the same IIS complete version (it's enough a virtual machine).